# Prove by induction $(1+x)^n > \frac {n(n-1)} 2 x^2$

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-theorem

This particular question looks like Bernoulli's inequality. I've looked at similar questions but am still stuck on this problem:
Show that 
$$ (1+x)^n > \frac {n(n-1)} 2 x^2 $$ for $x > 0$ and all positive integers $n$

The base case is obvious enough, then using the assumption

$$ (1+x)^k > \frac {k(k-1)} 2 x^2 $$

I also know I'm using this to prove
$$(1+x)^{k+1} > \frac {(k+1)k} 2 x^2 =  \frac {k(k-1)} 2 x^2 + kx^2$$

I'm multiplying by $(1+x)$ to use the inductive step

$$ (1+x)^{k+1} > \frac {k(k-1)} 2 x^2 + \frac {k(k-1)} 2 x^3   $$
which is not clear enough to me.

Comment: Prove the stronger inequality $$(1+x)^n \geqslant 1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^2.$$

Comment: I'm still unsure how to do it as such

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205090/prove-by-induction-on-n-that-when-x-gt-0-1xn-ge-1nx-fracnn-1) for a proof of that by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing your proof starting from the inductive step:

We need to prove that $(1+x)^k(1+x) = (1+x)^k + x(1+x)^k > \dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}x^2 + kx^2$

Knowing that $(1+x)^k > \dfrac{k(k-1)}{2}x^2$ we are left to show that $x(1+x)^k > kx^2$

$x(1+x)^k = x\sum_0^k{{k}\choose{i}}x^i = \sum_0^k{{k}\choose{i}}x^{i+1} = x + kx^2 + \sum_3^k{{k}\choose{i}}x^{i+1} > kx^2$

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for the good answer. It follows on nicely and a lot more intuitively than suggested by Fischer's link. Thank you.

Comment: If using the binomial theorem is admissable, then all we must do is to note that$$(1+x)^k=1+kx+\binom k2x^2+\cdots>\binom k2x^2=\frac{k(k-1)}2x^2.$$